# Two-dimensional array shorter than it's supposed to be

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    int size_plansza;
    scanf("%d",&size_plansza);
    char plansza[size_plansza][size_plansza];
    char pozycja;
    for (int i=0;i<size_plansza;i++)
    {
        for (int j=0;j<size_plansza;j++)
        {
            scanf("%c",&pozycja);
            plansza[i][j] = pozycja;
        }

    }

    printf("%s",plansza);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm making a simple "chessboard" which's size is decided by the first input. Afterwards I'm putting the pieces on it with 'size' amount of lines. Sadly the i loop stops after size-1 iterations while the j loop works fine. For example if my 'size' is 5 and I'm inputting

KQRBN

PPPPP

.....

ppppp

It stops after the 4th line and prints it out. I really don't understand why. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Where is space for the `'\0'`? And the actual `'\0'`? Without the `'\0'` you have a plain array of char... **not a string**!

Comment: It is probably also consuming the newline character as the last one.

Comment: A C string is a 1-dimensional array of characters that ends with a null byte. `plansza` is 2-dimensional and you never add the null terminators.

Comment: What exactly do you type? Do you press the Enter key after typing `KQRBN`? What output do you expect? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

to print it as one string you need to

1. Add '\n' as last character in the row
2. Add null terminating character at the end.

```
int main(void)
{
    int size_plansza = 6;
    char plansza[size_plansza][size_plansza + 1];
    char pozycja;
    for (int i=0;i<size_plansza;i++)
    {
        for (int j=0;j<size_plansza;j++)
        {
            plansza[i][j] = '0' + 10 * i + j;
        }
        plansza[i][size_plansza] = '\n';
    }
    plansza[size_plansza - 1][size_plansza] = 0;

    printf("%s",plansza);
    return 0;
}
```